# How to turn off line wrap in the Pico editor when performing 'crontab -e'

Tags: cron

I am inserting a cron instruction via `crontab -e`, and [Pico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pico_(text_editor)) is the editor.

But the line I am inserting is going into wrap mode and I can't save my cron file, because the subsequent line is in violation of the time settings.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

I merely put my cursor at the first character of the 2nd (wrapped) line and hit the backspace key

That moved the line up and together with the 1st line.

Then cron compiled nicely

Thanks for everyone's help

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Bash, it's simple:

```
export EDITOR="pico -w"
```

Run this in the shell and do:

```
crontab -e
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you do.

Comment: Well, running both commands from the command line didn't solve the wrapping issue

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off line wrap:

```
% EDITOR="pico -w" crontab -e
```

You can also set this for each time you invoke pico/nano by editing your `~/.picorc` or `~/.nanorc` and entering:

```
unset fill
unset softwrap
set nowrap
```

Comment: There are no picorc files on the server and about 20 nanorc files. Which nanorc should I edit?

Comment: Look at `/etc/nanorc` and see what defaults it is setting.

Comment: /etc/nanorc does not exist on my server